# how to add different clone objects to the HashTable in c#?

Tags: c#, hashtable, clone

i pass a key and object to a class instaance that needs to clone that object and store it in hastable along with the key. How can i do it???

Comment: i pass a key and object to  a class instaance that needs to clone that object and store it in hastable along with the key. How can i do it???

Comment: your question has already been answered jacob. You cannot insert duplicate keys in a hashtable, so if you must do it .. you have to override GetHashCode() and generate your own keys. But I would recommend you refactor your code to not need to do that. Needing to override GetHashCode() in app code is a sign that something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well GetHashCode() is virtual for this reason.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx